# how to execute a sequence of commands by a QProcess (Qt 5.13) without having to restart it each time with the new arguments

Tags: qt, arguments, restart, execute, qprocess

I am working on a project with Qt5, I have a problem with the use of QProcess is as follows:
I want to create a PowerShell process which has the role of intercepting a command sequence and executing them. the concern is that each time I execute a new command, I have to close the process and restart it with new arguments using the "start (processPath, arguments)" command.
is there a way to execute commands without having to restart it every time ??

Comment: You say `"the concern is that each time I execute a new command, I have to close the process and restart it..."`: why is that a concern?  Reusing a `QProcess` objects for sequential commands shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: J' ai un souci d'optimisation, je travail sur une application en temps réel, ou le temps de fermeture et relancement du process créé une latence considérable. Des suggestions svp ?

Comment: If, as you say, your concern is with regard to optimization, latency etc., then you need to provide a lot more detail as to why it's a problem.  Are the commands completely unrelated, or piped, or... what?

Comment: J'ai une application client serveur (tout comme le vnc), ou dans le côté du client j'envoi des commandes de contrôle de la souris, et dans le côté du serveur, je les intercepte et les exécute a l'aide d'un process powershell (click gauche, click droit, double click,...)